# C++ union initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I have the code:

```
class Vector4
{

public:
    union
    {
        float x,y,z,w;
        float v[4];
    };

    Vector4(float _x, float _y, float _z, float _w)
    : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector4 constructor: " << this->x << "; " << this->y << "; " << this->z << "; " << this->w << std::endl;
    }
};
```

As I remember in VC 7.1 everything was fine, but in VC 2010 I got warning:

> warning C4608: 'Vector4::y' has already been initialized by another
>   union member in the initializer list,
>   'Vector4::::Vector4::x'

And when I write:

```
Vector4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

I see in console:

> Vector4 constructor: 0; 0; 0; 0

Please tell me, what happening?

Comment: Did your code work in VC 7.1 or did it just fail silently?

Comment: Sorry guys!!! it is my mistake!!!! I wasted your time!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You unioned `x,y,z,w` all to each other: all four floats share the same memory space since every element of a union begins at the same memory address.

Instead, you want to put all of the vector elements in a struct, like this:

```
union {
    struct { float x, y, z, w; };
    float v[4];
};
```

Comment: What happens here with regard to structure packing rules?  Presumably this could be dangerous with a type that doesn't get packed into the structure contiguously.

Comment: `float x,y,z,w` and `float v[4]` are aligned the same way. Yes, it could be a problem if the inner struct contained, say `char c` at the start, but in this case it does not.